# set 9 patch from assets folder

Tags: android, imageview, nine-patch

How can I set imageView border from 9 patch file in assets folder?
I have tried this but didn't work.

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("borders/border1.9.png"), null);
imageView.setBackground(d);
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why is it an asset in the first place?

Comment: Normally, you put this kind of resources in drawables.

Comment: If your objective is to avoid any sort of density-based scaling, use `res/drawable-nodpi/` instead of `assets/`.

Answer (score 2):

9-Patch PNGs are compiled on build time.

Non compiled .9.PNG is a usual PNG and is loaded as is.

The build.xml describes the task to compile .9.pngs to the AAPT (Android Asset Packaging Tool).

You can't compile it on runtime, put you can precompile them with aapt:

```
 aapt.exe c -S <input-folder-with-images>  -C <outpout-folder>
```

Where: 'output-folder' has to exist

Comment: you can compile them yourself though with aapt